# Postgresql matching purchases with most recent device loggedin

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, window-functions, amazon-redshift

In my application, I store logins with user_id, device_id(ifa) and login date in table called sessios_logs. And I store purchases with user_id, amount and purchase date in table called purchases.

Below are the example outputs of these two tables where I try to match corresponding ifa values from session_logs for each purchase.

session_logs

```
uid         ifa  date
7560168721  CCC   1
7560168721  AAA   3
7560168721  BBB   5
7560168721  AAA   8
7560168721  AAA   10
```

purchases

```
uid       amount    date    <ifa>? 
7560168721   $1        2      CCC
7560168721   $9        4      AAA
7560168721   $5        7      BBB
7560168721   $4        11     AAA
```

So how can I find the closest login date and ifa value for each purchase?

I don't know how to iterate for each row while checking the maximum date in the session_logs and having login date earlier than purchase date.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "closest" I guess you mean closest given login date < purchase date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the window functions to match the purchase date to the closest session date.

```
SELECT uid, amount, date, ifa
FROM
    (SELECT
            t1.uid,
            t2.amount,
            t2.date AS date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.uid, t2.date) AS rn,
            t1.ifa
      FROM
            session_logs t1
            JOIN purchases t2 ON
                 t1.uid = t2.uid AND
                 t1.date <= t2.date) x1
WHERE x1.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    uid,
    amount,
    date,
    (
        select ifa
        from session_logs
        where
            uid = purchases.uid and
            date < purchases.date
        order by date desc
        limit 1
    )
from purchases;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window functions, however sadly they are not allowed in the `WHERE` part so hence there is a wrapper query around it:

```
select
  uid,
  amount,
  date,
  ifa
from
(
  select
    l.uid,
    amount,
    p.date as date,
    max(l.date) over (partition by l.uid, p.date) as max_date,
    l.ifa
  from
    session_logs l
    join purchases p on
      l.uid = p.uid and
      l.date <= p.date
  -- where l_date = max(l.date) over (partition by l.uid, p.date)
) t
where l_date=max_date;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/36185/9/0